# What is the white goo in the middle of some hard-boiled egg yolks?

Tags: food-safety, hard-boiled-eggs

My wife made some deviled eggs today, but found a surprise inside some of them after they were cooked. Right in the middle of the yolks was a tiny bit of some white goo, very different in color and consistency of the surrounding yolk.

What is this stuff? Was it safe to eat? We ended up tossing those eggs out because we had no clue.

UPDATE: my wife had taken a picture 
[image: Goop in the yolk]

Comment: And you didn't happen to take a picture before dumping them? Such a pity! Welcome to Seasoned Advice!  I see you already took the [tour], if you want to learn more, check out our [help].

Comment: Alas, no. Thought about it, but not enough to actually do so. There are more eggs from that package, so if we get any more, I'll post a picture.

Comment: imho this is the most delicious point to eat them - not quite hardboiled, not runny enough to dribble down your arm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is so called *white yolk*, aka [latebra](http://chickscope.beckman.uiuc.edu/explore/embryology/day01/the_yolk.html), present in any egg, with slightly higher protein content. Its precise function is unknown; it is believed to be a center of the egg development. Perfectly safe.

Comment: The site you link makes a distinction between white yolk and the latebra, with the latebra being a particular mass of white yolk, not a term for all white yolk.